Proof by contradiction, where is the contradiction?

Example. Let $F=\{E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_s\}$ be a family of subsets with $r$ elements of some set $X$.
Show that if the intersection of any $r+1$ (not necessarily distinct) sets in $F$ is nonempty, then the intersection of all sets in $F$ is nonempty.
Solution. Again we assume the contrary, namely that the intersection of all sets in $F$ is empty. Consider the set $E_1=\{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$.
Because none of the $x_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,r$, lies in the intersection of all the $E_j$'s (this intersection being empty), it follows that for each $i$ we can find some $E_{j_i}$ such that $x_i\notin E_{j_i}$.
Then $$E_1\cap E_{i_1}\cap E_{i_2}\cap\cdots\cap E_{i_r}=\emptyset,$$
since, at the same time, this intersection is included in $E_1$ and does not contain any element of $E_1$.
But this contradicts the hypothesis.
It follows that our initial assumption was false, and hence the sets from the family $F$ have a nonempty intersection.

I understand why the intersection of $E_1,E_{i_1},E_{i_2} \ldots$ is empty, but how does this fact contradict the hypothesis? More importantly, what exactly is the hypothesis?

The author has constructed $r+1$ members of the family $F$ and, by the assumptions of the problem, the intersection of such can not be empty.

Hi! It would really help future users of this site if the problem and solution were typeset in MathJax. Otherwise, it cannot be searched as effectively. As an example, $x_i \not\in E_{i_1} \cap E_{i_2}$ yields $x_i \not\in E_{i_1} \cap E_{i_2}$ and $\{a, b, c\}$ yields ${a, b, c}$.

More explicitly the hypothesis to disprove is that there is a family F with a non-empty intersection of $r+1$ sets and with the intersection of all sets in F being empty.

The "hypothesis" that the construction contradicts is that "the intersection of any $r+1$ (not necessarily distinct) sets in $F$ is nonempty."

I've edited your question to remove the image and replace it with properly type-set math. In the future, please do so yourself when asking a question. Also, please check to make sure I didn't accidentally introduce any mistakes into your question.

@Robert Shore Thank you. I thought that the hypothesis was "the intersection of any (ONE) (r+1(not necessarily distinct) sets) in F is nonempty." But the proof makes sense when you look at it as "the intersection of ALL combinations of  r+1(not necessarily distinct) sets in F is nonempty." Is this right?

@Shoe__gazer Yes, that explains your confusion.
